# IOCP CompletionKey for Boost::Asio?

Tags: boost, boost-asio, iocp

I'm creating a TCP server using `Boost::Asio`. I have to track the packet time for each client. When an IO operation is completed, I can easily identify each client using the completion keys returned by `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`. I can't find a way to do this with `Boost::Asio`.

How can I implement this or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly:
What is wrong with storing all client related state (sockets, addresses, etc.) in a class such as the session class in the [asio async tcp server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)? Then e.g you can start the timer when you call the `async::write` operation

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
      boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
      boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

and stop the timer in the write completion handler `handle_write` which will be invoked by asio once the write is complete.

```
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
```

Alternatively, you can easily use [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html) to keep state. E.g Say if you invoke an asynchronous write operation, you will specify the handler that will usually have a signature similar to `handle_write` with some additional parameters and bind an additional parameter to the call.

If this does not answer your question, add some further explanation to your question so that someone can better help you .